# Flutter web version of my app crashes when launched

Tags: flutter, dart, crash, flutter-web, multiplatform

Flutter web version of any app crashes when it's launched on Chrome, even when I launch a new project built from scratch (no modification, when Android Studio finishes building it, I launch it).

I receive this log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:52137/Ot39336ZDps=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52137/Ot39336ZDps=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52137/Ot39336ZDps=/ws
Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"27","method":"getMemoryUsage","params":{"isolateId":"1"}}
Application finished.
```

But it doesn't give me a lot of information about what's going on.

The weird part is that both iOS and Android versions of the app run perfectly.

I'm in the stable channel, using FLutter 2.5.2 and Dart 2.14.3

Comment: Make sure you have latest version of your IDE and the flutter plugin for your IDE, latest version of Chrome, and your firewall is off. Reboot your computer, try a flutter clean and then build and run again and see if that fixes the issue. This has been a recurring issue every time they update the intelliJ plugins. You can try flutter run in the terminal and it should work fine, the issue is mostly with Android Studio and IntelliJ

Comment: This happens with the terminal too. But I'll try to do everything else you mentioned.

Comment: Hey, try running `flutter run -d chrome --verbose` . It should continue failing, but it will give you a lot more logs to investigate on why(or share here)

Comment: run flutter clean and then try again

Comment: It seems that is has to do with the computer, because I'm using my workplace computer, and maybe there are some blocked ports. It works flawlessly on my personal computer, so I think I'll be working on that one. Thanks everyone for your help!